# How to create a Oracle 12c Database with Comandline without Fast Recovery

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to write a script which creates a Oracle Database. Is there a way to create one without Fast Recovery? What i did up untill now:

```
@echo off
set DBNAME=TEST
set SYSUSERPASSWORD=XXX
set SYSTEMUSERPASSWORD=XXX
set MEMORYPERCENTAGE=25
dbca -silent -createDatabase -templateName General_Purpose.dbc -gdbName
%DBNAME% -sid %DBNAME% -sysPassword %SYSUSERPASSWORD% -systemPassword
%SYSTEMUSERPASSWORD% -memoryPercentage %MEMORYPERCENTAGE%
pause
```

Which properly creates a Database but with Fast Recovery.

Comment: Copy and modify the response file?

Comment: I want to use the script on multiple pc´s and dont want to move the response file. Guess there is no other way ?@AlexPoole

Comment: Why can't you distribute your customised response file with the script?

Comment: Well i think i am just gonna do that. Thought there would be an easier way just by typing parameters. But thanks alot :) @AlexPoole